# Using a partial view across mutiple areas - MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I am wanting to use a view across multiple areas. I have put the partial view in question into the main application Views/Shared folder, but I cannot seem to access this.

Does anyone know how to access the shared view folder?

The code i am currently using is the basic:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("MyPartialControl")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using full path?

```
@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/MyPartialControl.cshtml")
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried using the full path but it does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: Could you update the question with detailed error message, please?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, if you have not found the solution yet (I doubt)... try this, it worked for me.

`@Html.RenderPartial("~\\Views\\Shared\\MyPartialControl.cshtml")` for C# and single '\' for VB.NET